# ionic 3 login -use websql. I could not get true or false from service

Tags: ionic3

I want to create a login with authentication using `websql`. I have to check whether the `username` and `password` exists in table. If exists I have to `return true` otherwise `false`.

Answer (score 0):

- List item

In service file
getAuthentication(UserName:string,UserPassword:string,CompanyName:string,nav:any):any{
    let result:Boolean;
    var db=this.windowref.nativeWindow.openDatabase('localdb','1.0','Testing Db',3*1024*1024);
    result=db.transaction(function(tx){
      tx.executeSql(`select UM.UserName,UM.UserPassword,CM.CompName from table1UM inner join table2 CM 
      on UM.CompanyId=CM.CompId where UM.UserName=? and UM.UserPassword=? and CM.CompName=?`
      ,[UserName,UserPassword,CompanyName],
      function(tx,rs){
        if(rs.rows.length>0){
         result= true;
        }
        else{
           result= false;
        }
      },
      function(tx,error){
        console.log("record fetching erro:"+error.message);
      })return result;
    });
i want to get true or false in component.